# Копирование связанных данных

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть три таблицы: `Objs, Attrs и Binds` - в одной лежат объекты, в другой всевозможные параметры, в третьей - соответствия объектов и принадлежащих им параметрам, т.е. ссылки на эти данные. Как сделать копию части данных таблиц `Objs` и `Binds`, и вставить в эти же таблицы, чтобы соответствия между данными сохранилось? При этом поле `Id` в таблицах `Objs` и `Attrs` уникальные и автогенерируемые.
Структура данных:

```
CREATE TABLE Objs(
  Id INT IDENTITY
 ,Name NVARCHAR(256) NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Objs_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE TABLE Attrs(
  Id INT IDENTITY
 ,Name NVARCHAR(256) NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Attrs_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE TABLE Binds(Obj_Id INT, Attr_Id INT);
ALTER TABLE Binds
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Binds_Objs_Id FOREIGN KEY (Obj_Id) REFERENCES Objs (Id);
ALTER TABLE Binds
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Binds_Attrs_Id FOREIGN KEY (Attr_Id) REFERENCES Attrs (Id);
GO
```

Пример:

```
+------------------------+    +-------------------+    +--------------------+
| Objs                   |    | Attrs             |    | Binds              |
+--------+---------------+    +--------+----------+    +--------+-----------+
| Id     | Name          |    | Id     | Name     |    | Obj_Id | Attr_Id   | 
+--------+---------------+    +--------+----------+    +--------+-----------+
| 1      | Круг          |    | 1      | Длина    |    | 1      | 5         | 
| 2      | Прямоугольник |    | 2      | Ширина   |    | 2      | 1         | 
| 3      | Конус         |    | 3      | Высота   |    | 2      | 2         | 
+--------+---------------+    | 4      | Глубина  |    | 3      | 5         | 
                              | 5      | Радиус   |    | 3      | 3         | 
                              | 6      | Скорость |    +--------+-----------+
                              | 7      | Масса    |
                              | 8      | Время    |
                              +--------+----------+
```

Нужно скопировать Прямоугольник и Конус из таблицы Objs и вставить в неё же, а затем всавить соответствия в таблицу Attrs, чтоб в итоге получилось

```
+------------------------+        +---------------------+
| Objs                   |        | Binds               |
+--------+---------------+        +---------+-----------+
| Id     | Name          |        | Obj_Id  | Attr_Id   | 
+--------+---------------+        +---------+-----------+
| 1      | Круг          |        | 1       | 5         | 
| 2      | Прямоугольник |        | 2       | 1         | 
| 3      | Конус         |        | 2       | 2         | 
| 4      | Прямоугольник |        | 3       | 5         |
| 5      | Конус         |        | 3       | 3         |
+--------+---------------+        | 4       | 1         |
                                  | 4       | 2         |
                                  | 5       | 5         |
                                  | 5       | 3         |
                                  +---------+-----------+
```

Чтоб сделать копирование данных в `Objs и Binds` и сохранить соответствия в таблице Binds, я могу делать копирование данных в цикле - копировать нужные данные из таблицы Objs, вставлять их в неё, получать новый Id, затем получить данные их таблицы Attrs с нужным Obj_Id, вставить эти данные в таблицу, подменяя старый Obj_Id на новый.
Проблема в том, что копируемых данных может быть очень много и нельзя использовать циклы, т.к. циклы в sql запросе сильно тормозят его выполнение, а мне важна скорость обработки запроса.

Исходя из всего этого имеются вопросы:

1. Думаю это типичная задача копирования связанных данных. Подскажите, где можно посмотреть алгоритм такого копирования, или, если знаете, расскажите его?
2. Могу я быть уверен в том, что команда INSERT INTO вставит данные в таблицу строго в той последовательности, в которой я ей их передам?

Comment: *2. Могу я быть уверен в том, что команда INSERT INTO вставит данные в таблицу строго в той последовательности, в которой я ей их передам?* Таблица - это несортированная куча. И никакой "последовательности" там нет в принципе. Порядок следования записи появляется только в результате запроса, если имется соответствующий ORDER BY. *1. Думаю это типичная задача копирования связанных данных.* Это да. Вот только Вы как-то не озаботились показать структуру хранения, ограничившись лишь примером данных. А потому пока даже нет убеждённости, что у Вас данные - СВЯЗАННЫЕ.

Comment: @Akina, не хотел загромождать вопрос, который и так не маленький, кодом создания таблиц и связей между ними. Думаю, из названия колонок в таблице `Binds` ясно, что они имеют связь с конкретными колонками конкретных таблиц.

Comment: И всё же сделайте это... заодно уточните - возможны ли параллельные вставки? Вообще - такие операции лучше оформлять в виде хранимой процедуры, тогда несложно получать необходимые значения автоинкрементов и сохранять их в переменных для использования в следующих запросах процедуры.

Comment: @Akina, добавил код создания таблиц и связей между ними

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> алгоритм такого копирования

Обычно создаётся таблица соответствия:

```
CREATE TABLE #Mapping (Existing_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, New_Id int NOT NULL);
```

Потом копируются нужные данные в основной таблице, а в таблицу соответствия выводятся пары идентификаторов (существующее/новое, оригинал/копия):

```
MERGE INTO Objs T
USING (
    SELECT Id, Name
    FROM Objs
    WHERE Name in (N'Прямоугольник', N'Конус')
) S
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Name)
    VALUES (S.Name)
OUTPUT S.Id, INSERTED.Id INTO #Mapping (Existing_Id, New_Id);
```

Затем копируются данные в остальных таблицах:

```
INSERT INTO Binds (Obj_Id, Attr_Id)
SELECT
    m.New_Id, b.Attr_Id
FROM Binds b
    JOIN #Mapping m ON m.Existing_Id = b.Obj_Id;
```

> Могу я быть уверен в том, что команда INSERT INTO вставит данные в
>   таблицу строго в той последовательности, в которой я ей их передам

Если только вставлять по одной строке за раз. В общем случае порядок вставки считается неопределённым. Смысла вставлять строки в каком-то определённом порядке мало, т.к. порядок вставки не гарантирует какой-либо порядок хранения или последующей выборки. При грамотном подходе такой потребности не должно возникать.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Вы открыли для меня OUTPUT